# Installing Anaconda on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk to use in Django application

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, anaconda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django application which it's deployed to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. I have to install anaconda for installing pythonocc-core package. I have created a `.config` file in `.ebextensions` folder and add the anaconda path in my wsgi.py file such as below and I have deployed it successfully.

.config file:

```
commands:
  00_download_conda:
    command: 'wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh'
    test: test ! -d /anaconda
  01_install_conda:
    command: 'bash Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /anaconda'
    test: test ! -d /anaconda
  02_create_home:
    command: 'mkdir -p /home/wsgi'
  03_conda_activate_installation:
    command: 'source ~/.bashrc'
```

wsgi.py:

```
sys.path.append('/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
```

However when I add the `04_conda_install_pythonocc` command below to the continuation of this .config file, I got `command failed` error.

```
04_conda_install_pythonocc: 
command: 'conda install -c dlr-sc pythonocc-core=7.4.0'
```

I ssh into the instance for checking. I saw the /anaconda folder has occured. When I checked with the `conda --version` command, I got the `-bash: conda: command not found` error.

Afterwards, I thought there might be a problem with the PATH and I edited the `.config` file as follows and I have deployed this .config file successfully.

```
commands:
  00_download_conda:
    command: 'wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh'
    test: test ! -d /anaconda
  01_install_conda:
    command: 'bash Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /anaconda'
    test: test ! -d /anaconda
  02_create_home:
    command: 'mkdir -p /home/wsgi'
  03_add_path:
    command: 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda/bin'
  04_conda_activate_installation:
    command: 'source ~/.bashrc'
```

But when I add the `conda_install_pythonocc` command again to the continuation of this edited version of .config file, it failed again and I got `command failed`.

In manually, all the commands work but they don't work in my .config file.

How can I fix this issue and install package with conda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to **replicated** the issue on my sandbox account, and I successful installed conda using the following (simplified) config file on `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.3 running Python 3.7`:

**.ebextensions/60_anaconda.config**

```
commands:
  00_download_conda:
    command: 'wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh'
  01_install_conda:
    command: 'bash Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /anaconda'
  05_conda_install: 
    command: '/anaconda/bin/conda install -y -c dlr-sc pythonocc-core=7.4.0'
```

Note the use off **absolute path** `/anaconda/bin/conda` and `-y` to not ask for **manual confirmations**. I only **verified installation** procedure, not how to use it afterwards (e.g. not how to use it in python application). Thus you will probably need to adjust it to your needs.

The **EB log file** showing successful installation is also provided for your reference (shortened for simplicity):

- [/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log](https://pastebin.com/raw/t7TNMigi)

Comment: My build failed because of the 05_conda_install command according to my logs.

Comment: @AslıKök Which environment are you using? Same as I used for verification? As you see in my logs, there were no problems installing anaconda. Is the error msg same with my code?

Comment: I'm using 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.3 running Python 3.7. My commands are the same with yours. I have also tried to creating a new environment and deploying but it failed again.

Comment: Error occurred during build: Command 02_conda_install_pythonocc failed

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 71: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 502

Comment: @AslıKök what is `02_conda_install_pythonocc`?  Its not in my answer nor in your original question?

Comment: @AslıKök Don't know at present. I wonder why python 2.7 would be used (`"/usr/lib64/python2.7`) though. The new error seems that some encoding issues are present. Maybe you have some strange characters somewhere in your config files?

Comment: I remove the install_anaconda config file from ebextensions and my environment is okay, now I will try to deploy with that config file again.

Comment: @AslıKök Let me know how it will go.

Comment: Omg, deployment is successfull. Now can I import pythonocc-core directly to my .py file now?

Comment: Even though I did not change anything and did not re-deploy, the environment health in severe state again.

Comment: @AslıKök So the conda installation worked? There could be other reasons why your health is severe. Maybe you run out of resources or your application crasshed?

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: @AslıKök Same as before. Have to inspect logs. But I understand the conda got installed? If some, maybe new question would be better if this is new issue?

Comment: oh I solve the issue, it was about the disk space. Thank you, your commands work!

Comment: @AslıKök No problem. Glad it worked out. And thanks for letting me know.